# My AJAX with forms is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

```
        <?php
            session_start();
            if (isset($_POST['sub']))
            {
                    $email=$_POST['email'];

                    if ($email=="")
                    {
                        echo "enter mail";
                    }
                    else {
                        $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pdo","root","");
                        $correct=$db->prepare("select * from sub where email=:email");
                        $correct->bindParam(":email",$email);
                        $correct->execute();    
                            if ($correct->rowCount()==0)
                            {
                                echo "no mail found pls check";
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                            while ($row=$correct->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
            echo "Secutity question:<input type='text' id='ques' value='$row[question]' name='question' readonly>".
                        "<br><br>"."<b>Answer:</b>&nbsp;"."<input type='text' id='ans' placeholder='answer' name='answer' style='border:1px solid black;width:100px'>".
                    "&nbsp;<br>".
                    "<span class='result' style=color:red'></span>";
            echo "<input type='submit' id='chek123' name='newpwd' value='reset pwd'>";
    }   }   }   }       ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#chek123").click(function()
                {
                    var ques = $("#ques").val();
                    var ans = $("#ans").val();
                        if(ans=="")
                        {
                            $(".result").text("answer empty");
                        }
                        else {
                            $.ajax({
                                url:'securitycheck.php,
                                type:'POST',
                                data:{ques1:ques,ans1:ans},
                                success:function(data)
                                {
                                    if(data=="enter ans"){
                                        $(".result").text(data);
                                    }
                                    else if(data=="answer is wrong")
                                    {
                                        $(".result").text(data);                                
                                    }
                                    else if(data=="valid")
                                        {
                                        window.location = "newpwd.php";
                                    }
                                    else {}
                                }
                            });
                            }               
                });

            });
        </script>
```

My code is not working. Input type submit is not showing any response when click on it and even doesn't not running condition from PHP.
     Also even when the answer is correct it also then not showing any response and it did not directing to newpwd.php page. I don't know Why?
    When I click on input type submit even when answer field is empty it also then not showing error from AJAX.
 I'm totally tired working on this code from last 1 week.

Comment: "not working" means what exactly?

Comment: means not show any error or result when i click on the input type submit

Comment: In your browser hit F12 > Network and verify if there's any traffic at all when submitting.

Comment: i didn't get you? @ole

Comment: Press F12 and open the network tab. Then click on the button. Does anything happen in that tab? Whats the response of your request?

Comment: what to do in newtwork tab?

Comment: You are creating inputs within a `while` loop and giving them the same `id` each time through the loop.  Each element must have a unique/distinct `id`, especially if you are attaching event handlers to those elements.

Comment: then what to do sir #Patrick

Comment: Click on the button. Does anything happen in that tab? Whats the response of your request?

Comment: nothing happen sir

Comment: jshint.com shows a mass of syntax errors for the javascript.

Comment: in ajax url you missed closing quote(').

Comment: life saver sir its now working thanks sir @prasanna

Comment: You need to come up with a scheme for generating unique ids for your elements.  Likely something based on the loop iteration count.  You should then bind your click handler based on a class instead an id (since you don't want to have one handler per button).

Comment: I vote to close because the fundamental problem of the question was a typo. There are far more logistical issues, but that goes beyond the question.

Comment: What does closing a question on stackoverflow because it falls clearly into the 'off topic' realm have to do with anyone being a professional or not? :)

Comment: so whats the on topic so that i work on it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Too vague to help you out but you could start to debug the following code to check what you get at the console. type `submit` submits the form so you need to `preventDefault()` if I understand it correctly.

```
$("#chek123").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var ques = $("#ques").val();
    var ans = $("#ans").val();
    console.log({ques1:ques,ans1:ans});
});
```

Comment: "Too vague to help you out"  Then you shouldn't be posting an answer

Comment: I am just trying to help with whatever information is there. I am not sure if that breaks any of Stackoverflow house rule.

Comment: It does. Please see [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and maybe spend some time familiarizing yourself with other standards of the site.

Comment: @banstola it's good that you want to help, but answering vague questions is non-advisable. If the question is rewritten to be more specific, then your answer will either be incomplete or irrelevant. I hope you understand the reason behind it. It's not that we *don't* want your help, it's rather about helping optimally so that nobody wastes their time (here - you, answering the question). If you want to guide the OP to improve their question, you'll be able to do that by leaving a comment after you get 50rep.

Comment: @banstola - ^^ what these guys said. I'm going to flag this post for removal but that's just part of administering the site. Please follow the recommendations and from Patrick Q and AI. G and feel free to answer away once you read what an acceptable answer is!